# Azure Cognitive Search: Search only content owned by user - Over 100k items

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-cognitive-search

We have a subscriber-only area of our website where users can search the items they own. The most items a user can own is currently about 200,000. According to Microsoft, `search.in(...)` can be used to "filter thousands of values with sub-second response times."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-trimming-for-azure-search

> One way to achieve security filtering is through a complicated disjunction of equality expressions: for example, Id eq 'id1' or Id eq 'id2', and so forth. This approach is error-prone, difficult to maintain, and in cases where the list contains **hundreds or thousands of values**, slows down query response time by many seconds.
>
> A simpler and faster approach is through the search.in function. If
>   you use search.in(Id, 'id1, id2, ...') instead of an equality
>   expression, **you can expect sub-second response times**.

Passing in ~150k values to `search.in(...)` takes about 4-8 seconds to return results, compared to the ~.5 seconds a normal search takes. This is with the `search.in(...)` taking a list of item IDs and comparing them against the item ID (key field, filterable) in our index.

Is there a better way to do this? I'd really like to get the search down to < 1 second.

Comment: Can you share some details about your pricing tier and topology (number of partitions and replicas)?

Comment: 1 replica, 1 partition. Not sure where to find anything beyond that. It's very expensive to scale so we're hesitant to do this, and would like to ensure the way we're retrieving result is optimal rather than just throwing more money at it.

Comment: You should be able to tell what the pricing tier is from the Azure portal. Is it Basic, S1...?

Comment: On the Search Service Overview page, I'm seeing "Pricing Tier: Standard."

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Query performance can depend on a lot of factors, but from what you've told me, none of the obvious ones explain the latency you're seeing. Would you mind e-mailing me directly (bruce dot johnston at microsoft) with the following details: Service name, Azure region, approximate date/time of your most recent latency observations? Then we can take a closer look. Just to set expectations, I can't guarantee you can reach sub-second response time with your current setup, but maybe we can see if there's something else we can change.